# how to remove highligt/background color from bullet point in MS word 2019?

Tags: ms-word

I am looking for a way to clear the highlight from bullet point.
When i select it high is displaying no color.

[image]

Comment: You could try selecting the item before it all the way to the word "Fix", turning on highlighting, and then turning it off. That might work... but how is this about programming? Are you trying to automate doing that...?

Comment: This is not a programming question. As such it is off-topic here. Your question should be posted on an appropriate end-user site, such as MS Answers.

Comment: In my case, I had to select my complete list (not only the highlighted item) and even a bit of the text above and below the list, then turn on highlighting for the whole selection, then turn it off again, to make a highlighted bullet disappear. I agree it's not a programming question – hope this helps, anyway.